# Ошибка "NameError: name 'status' is not defined" при выполнении запроса к БД

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Переношу телеграмм бота с бд на сервер, запустил => пишет мол NameError: name 'status' is not defined
когда пытаюсь взять значение.

```
    def get_index_for_ifo_pay(self,):

    with self.connection:
       return self.cursor.execute("SELECT text FROM `subscriptions` WHERE 'status' = 1 AND 'status_car' = 1 ' ", (status,status_car )).fetchall()
```

Вот часть из кода - на этом месте пишет ошибку.

Comment: может потому что `name 'status' is not defined`?

Comment: У тебя `'status'` - это строковый литерал, тогда как по смыслу это вроде бы поле таблицы... используй правильные кавычки.

Comment: @timur спасибо конечно, я это понял - но как решить

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, но какие это правильные кавычки, если "", не подходит

Comment: @SpranjniyMops очевидно, определить переменную `status`

Comment: @SpranjniyMops вам стоит разобраться с кавычками в запросе, как минимум `'status_car' = 1 ' "` после 1 одинарная лишняя

Comment: @SergBocharov  def get_index_for_ifo_pay(self,):

  with self.connection:
     return self.cursor.execute("SELECT text FROM `subscriptions` WHERE status = 1 AND status_car = 1  ", (status,status_car )).fetchall()

Comment: @SergBocharov убрал все возможные скобки кроме одной пары "", но ничего не поменялось

Comment: К слову, на локальном сервере всё работает хорошо - запускаю через pycharm - и всё хорошо - а когда вот на сервер только закинул - такая проблема

Comment: @SergBocharov Они не определяются, на pycharm не нужно было - и так работало// больше кода ничего не дадут там просто подключение к бд через путь и в другом фале .ру файл который берёт этот класс и я потом вызываю через него. Помоги пожалуйста - как правильно определить если у меня в бд есть таблица из названием Status

Comment: @SpranjniyMops Так, стоп. У вас в запросе явно указано, что ''status' = 1 AND 'status_car' = 1 '', что вообще за переменные тогда и для чего?

Comment: @SergBocharov Мне нужно взять "текст" тех колонок - где статус 1 и статус_сар = 1

Comment: @SergBocharov вот тип sql - код SELECT text FROM `subscriptions` WHERE status = 1 AND status_car = 1  "

Comment: @SpranjniyMops я может чего-то не понимаю, но эти переменные должны подставляться в тело запроса, и они не подставляются ибо в запросе нет переменных, т.е. их можно спокойно убрать или получить в них данные из запроса: `res=self.cursor.execute("SELECT text FROM subscriptions WHERE status = 1 AND status_car = 1").fetchall()  status=res[0] status_car = res[1] return status, status_car `